# Ionic v4 Firebase: cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

This code has been bugging me for a good four hours... It's supposed to sign up a user with Firebase's auth system and Ionic 4 components.

Instead it returns the following around a good *six* times:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Another weird thing is that my code will only nitpick on the property 'email', and won't return errors for having a property 'password'.

**signup.page.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

// firebase imports
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

// model import 
import { User } from '../../models/login.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.page.scss'],
})
export class SignupPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private route: Router,
    public toast: ToastController
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async signup(user: User) {
    console.log('starting auth');
    try {
      const result = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      if (result) {
          this.route.navigateByUrl('/add-profile');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

}
```

**signup.page.html**

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>SIGNUP</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Password (6+ characters)</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="signup(user)">SIGNUP
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

**user.interface.ts**

```js
export interface User {
  email: string;
  pasword: string;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a user and initialize it with empty values either in constructor or ngOnInit like below

user:User;

//inside constructor or ngOnInit
this.user = {
 email: '',
  pasword: ''
}

Answer (score 0):

```
// firebase imports
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

// model import 
import { User } from '../../models/login.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.page.scss'],
})
export class SignupPage implements OnInit {

  user: User = {
  email: '',
  password: ''  
  }
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private route: Router,
    public toast: ToastController
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async signup(user: User) {
    console.log('starting auth');
    try {
      const result = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      if (result) {
          this.route.navigateByUrl('/add-profile');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

}
```